# Querying a record from a list<frozen<UDT>>

Tags: c#, cassandra, cqlsh, user-defined-types

I'm trying to query a record by using the WHERE clause, but Datastax and the cassandra sites don't have the information for what I want to do. I want to query a record that has a column as **`list<frozen<phone>>`** named phones. So I.m using cqlsh to query it but I can't find the right documentation or keywords for it.

this is the UDT I have created
create type casstestrun.phone (cellnumber text, faxnumber text, officenumber text);

This the table I have created

```
create table casstestrun.customer (cid uuid, cname text, phones list<frozen<phone>>);
```

so, my question is how to query a record from a `list<frozen<udt>>`?

is it something like this select*from casstestrun.customer where phones.celnumber = '222-222-2222';

Answer (score 0):

There's information on how to deal with [user-defined types (UDT) in the documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.4/features/udts/).

You should create a mapping between the UDT and a C# class once.

```
session.UserDefinedTypes.Define(
   UdtMap.For<Phone>()
);
```

Then you can retrieve and update rows containing `phone` values:

```
var row = session.Execute(statement).First();
var phones = row.GetValue<IEnumerable<Phone>>("phones");
```